# Laravel installed with composer not working any hints?

Tags: laravel

I just installed laravel with composer on windows 8.1
Created a new project using composer...
I am  getting this error when i browse to /public/

any help will be appreciated.
    RuntimeException in E:\xampp\htdocs\lar\web\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29: No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

```
in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29
```

Answer (score 5):

Just found the solution never mind!

the default cipher in confing/app.php is "AES-256-CBC" which needs a 32 character string, but the default key is "SomeRandomString," which is only 16 characters.

So, you can either set the cipher to "AES-128-CBC" which only needs 16 characters, or generate a new 32 character string for the key. Entering "php artisan key:generate" is the simplest solution.